# Clicking button does nothing

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

I'm trying to make a program that takes 5 words from a database randomly and inserts them into an array. The page initially loads as desired, but nothing happens after the button is clicked. None of the alerts are ever triggered, so the function must never be entered, but why is beyond me. Also, I get an error saying name isn't a legitimate index (referencing line 13) the first time I try running it on a browser, so advice about that would be great too.

lingo.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (empty($_POST["name"])):
       $_SESSION["error"] = "You did not enter a name.";
       header("Location: entername.php");
    else:
       $name = $_POST["name"];
       setcookie("name", "$name", time()+3600);
    endif;
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <b>Welcome to Lingo, <?php echo $_COOKIE["name"]; ?></b><br />
    <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    var arr = [];
    function collectWords() {
        $.post("getWord.php",
    function(data) {
        arr[word1] = $(data).find("Word1").text();
        alert("function reached");
        alert(arr[word1]);
        arr[word2] = $(data).find("Word2").text();
        alert(arr[word2]);
        arr[word3] = $(data).find("Word3").text();
        alert(arr[word3]);
        arr[word4] = $(data).find("Word4").text();
        alert(arr[word4]);
        arr[word5] = $(data).find("Word5").text();
        alert(arr[word5]);
    });
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id = "theTable" border = "1" class = "thetable"> </table>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Start" onclick = "collectWords()">
  </body>
</html>
```

getWord.php

```
<?php
   $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'spj916', "cs4501", 'spj916');
   if ($db->connect_error):
      die ("Could not connect to db " . $db->connect_error);
   endif;

   $query = "select word from Words order by rand() limit 1";
   $result = $db->query($query);
   $rows = $result->num_rows;
   if ($rows >= 1):
      header('Content-type: text/xml');
      echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
      echo "<Word1>";
      $row = $result->fetch_array();
      $ans = $row["word"];
      echo "<value>$ans</value>";
      echo "</Word1>";
   else:
      die ("DB Error");
   endif;

   $query = "select word from Words order by rand() limit 1";
   $result = $db->query($query);
   $rows = $result->num_rows;
   if ($rows >= 1):
      header('Content-type: text/xml');
      echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
      echo "<Word2>";
      $row = $result->fetch_array();
      $ans = $row["word"];
      echo "<value>$ans</value>";
      echo "</Word2>";
   else:
      die ("DB Error");
   endif;

   $query = "select word from Words order by rand() limit 1";
   $result = $db->query($query);
   $rows = $result->num_rows;
   if ($rows >= 1):
      header('Content-type: text/xml');
      echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
      echo "<Word3>";
      $row = $result->fetch_array();
      $ans = $row["word"];
      echo "<value>$ans</value>";
      echo "</Word3>";
   else:
      die ("DB Error");
   endif;

   $query = "select word from Words order by rand() limit 1";
   $result = $db->query($query);
   $rows = $result->num_rows;
   if ($rows >= 1):
      header('Content-type: text/xml');
      echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
      echo "<Word4>";
      $row = $result->fetch_array();
      $ans = $row["word"];
      echo "<value>$ans</value>";
      echo "</Word4>";
   else:
      die ("DB Error");
   endif;

   $query = "select word from Words order by rand() limit 1";
   $result = $db->query($query);
   $rows = $result->num_rows;
   if ($rows >= 1):
      header('Content-type: text/xml');
      echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
      echo "<Word5>";
      $row = $result->fetch_array();
      $ans = $row["word"];
      echo "<value>$ans</value>";
      echo "</Word5>";
   else:
      die ("DB Error");
   endif;
?>
```

Comment: Your Javascript is correct. Get the response from the Ajax and check is that is returned successfully. Like this: `$.post("getWord.php",
    function(data, response){ console.log(response)});`. Also what is the `data` value that you are posting? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: I thought that was just proper syntax, I've seen it in every example I've been given, and it's worked for a program I've already gotten to work, so I continued to put it there. Also, I added that line to my function and nothing comes up in the console.

Comment: It's proper syntax for a jquery ajax. The function is the success function and the (data) is the data the ajax call gets back. You can name it whatever you want. You can name it json or cheese or data, doesn't matter.

Comment: @BobJones Roy was suggesting that you add `$.post("getWord.php", function(data, response){ console.log(response)});` to your html because it's a short, simple way of checking whether or not your front-end is actually receiving any data from your php script. Try fetching your php script manually in the browser and see what you get. Search google or SO for "enable error reporting php" in case the problem seems php related. Where do you handle the post data on the server? Can't see it anywhere; did I miss it? Should you really be using `$.get`? Where do you define `word1`, `word2`, etc.?

Comment: Sorry about suggesting to set the `data` part. I have been fetching content with Angular for last 1 whole year. And now when I saw `$.post` I mixed it up thinking you are about to post something to the server using the `data` variable. And I haven't slept for more than 36 hours. :D Sorry again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error on `$_COOKIE["name"];` because said cookie isn't set until you set it. You don't set the cookie until someone has entered their names, so on the first load it will give an error.

http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/set-cookies.shtml
"Note that you cannot set a cookie in PHP and hope to retrieve the cookie immediately in that same script session. Take the following non-working PHP code as an example:"

Found under the header: "How to get the contents of a cookie.

Fix this with a shorthand if statement, like so:

```
<b>Welcome to Lingo,
 <?php isset($_COOKIE["name"]) ? $_COOKIE["name"] : $_POST["name"]; //Checks if the cookie is set. If not, uses the $_POST name ?>! </b><br />
```

I have another question:
Why are your words requested 1 at a time? Why not get all 5 words in 1 query? Also, why send them back as XML data? Since you seem to be handling the data yourself, I would personally recommend a simple loop on the PHP side, returning it as a handy pre-made JSON array.
**edit: Also important, PHP does not echo any content automatically. An AJAX call can only receive printed data. You need to echo your results at the end of your php script or you will return nothing**

Like so:

```
   $query = "select word from Words order by rand() limit 5";
   $result = $db->query($query);
   $rows = $result->num_rows;
   $array = array();
   if ($rows >= 1):

$i = 0;//start the wordcount
//While there are results, loop. (Results are limited to 5, so it won't loop more than 5 times)
while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
  $i++;//Put this on top so it starts with "1"
  $array["word$i"] = $row[0]; //create the array
}
echo json_encode($array); //Turn array into json and echo it.
      else:
      die ("DB Error");
   endif;
```

Now, you will also need to change your `Javascript`side a tiny bit.
This is how you will access the new array (created by php)

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
function collectWords() {
    $.post("getWord.php",
function(data) {
alert(data); // show whether you get any data back in the first place. thanks @jDo
var arr = $.parseJSON(data);

    alert(arr.word1);
    alert(arr.word2);
    alert(arr.word3);
    alert(arr.word4);
    alert(arr.word5);
});
}
</script>
```

As you can see, this way saves you quite a lot of code and saves you a **lot** of word replacements

Comment: Does this mean that the html is executed before the php? The cookie should be set once the conditional is entered, the post data is coming from a prior script.

Comment: I no longer have a name come up any time that it runs, and when I click the button, I get an error on the console saying "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: @BobJones remove all this: `var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(arr.word1);
    alert(arr.word2);
    alert(arr.word3);
    alert(arr.word4);
    alert(arr.word5);` and do `alert(data)` instead for testing. Add it in again later.

Comment: @BobJones ok, that's an error from your php script being passed to the frontend. Now search for `fetchRow` in your php and change it to `fetch_row`. Why isn't that in the php script you posted? Did you post all the code?

Comment: @jDo it's not in his question because it's in **my** answer. I rewrote his script ;)

Comment: I did put fetch_row() in the code, I just mistyped it in my comment

Comment: Sorry, **my mistake!** I've gotten used to my own dbclass, it works differently in standard mysqli object. Let me edit my answer quickly!

`$db->fetch_row($result)` should be `$result->fetch_row()`

Comment: Now it says word1 is not defined when I click the button and it says the error is at line 10 which is impossible

Comment: Does it say this about the php script or is it a javascript error?
I'm going to assume javascript; Can you post the response you get in the `alert(data)` here?
Also, do remember that we do not know what line 10 is here.

Comment: Yes it's javascript, line 10 is just the line "?>". Alert(data) gives me {"word1":"after\t\n","word2":"heard\t\t\n","word3":"study\t\t\n","word4":"below\t\t\n","word5":"stand\t\t\n"}, which seems good. So then I tried alert(arr[word1]) and that's where the error comes up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108729/discussion-between-babydead-and-bob-jones).